# Change brush outline color

Tags: image, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I am doing a simple texture paint. The problem is that, in the texture paint image, there are parts where it is completely white. This makes it pretty much impossible to see the brush outline unless I bring it out of the border. (I mean that little circle that shows how big your brush is). Is there a way to change its color so it is more visible?

Here is a gif for better understanding:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure! You can do it here (see below):

[image: CircleCOlor]